# Excel to matlab timestamps

Tags: excel, matlab

I have data in excel in form of timestamps s it looks like

```
30/11/12 12:42 AM
30/11/12 12:47 AM
30/11/12 12:56 AM
30/11/12 1:01 AM
```

I need to get it to matlab to look like this

```
dateStrings = {...
'30/11/12 12:42 AM' ...
'30/11/12 12:47 AM' ...
'30/11/12 12:56 AM' ...
'30/11/12 1:01 AM' ...
 };
```

I have tried xlsread but it doesn't put in the strings.

Comment: How is the data stored in the Excel sheet? What do you get instead of the strings? What is the exact syntax of `xlsread` that you used?

Comment: in the form of a time data format so as you can see it, well instead of strings it doesn't read anything, dateStr = xlsread('C:\Users\Ondra\Dropbox\Thesis\Matlab\Room.xls','Data');

Comment: Is it one column containing the data? Do you get an empty array for that?

Comment: Yep it is one column with the data, nothing else

Comment: yep, I do get an empty array from this

Comment: Does it not just read as numbers instead of text?

Comment: Have you looked at all three outputs of `xlsread`? Also once you find the dates, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250339/use-dates-from-excel-in-matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me (in Octave, but should be the same in MATLAB):

```
>> [num,txt,raw]=xlsread('dates.xls','A1:A4')
num =

  4.1243e+004
  4.1243e+004
  4.1243e+004
  4.1243e+004

txt = {}(0x0)
raw =
{
  [1,1] = 4.1243e+004
  [2,1] = 4.1243e+004
  [3,1] = 4.1243e+004
  [4,1] = 4.1243e+004
}

>> datestr(num+datenum(1900,1,1,0,0,0)-2)
ans =

30-Nov-2012 00:42:00
30-Nov-2012 00:47:00
30-Nov-2012 00:56:00
30-Nov-2012 01:01:00

>> whos ans
Variables in the current scope:

Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
==== ====        ====                     =====  =====
    ans         4x20                        80  char

Total is 80 elements using 80 bytes
```

Check out the [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) function for the various output format options.

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find a way how to solve it

```
1. Copy and paste your dates into Excel in dd-mm-yyyy format
2. In Excel, highlight the data and go Right Click, Format Cells/Number
3. In Matlab go a=xlsread(xlsfile);
4. Type datestr(a+693960)
```